# Granting Roles on Group Of People

Tags: oracle, role

Is there anyway to grant specific roles on group of people such as :

```
Grant SELECT ON Jsmith To (SELECT user_name FROM dba_users);
```

However, this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Balazs Papp gave your answer. But just to add a note, try to use Roles on your database, to help you on future changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
begin
  for u in (select username from dba_users)
  loop
    execute immediate 'grant select on jsmith to "' || u.username || '"';
  end loop;
end;
/
```